# Can I programmatically export class diagrams from Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, documentation, sandcastle, class-diagram, helpfile

I can export a class diagram as an image from Visual Studio by right-clicking on the surface and choosing "Export Diagram as Image..."

Is there a way to do this through command line?   I'd like to be able to generate all of my class diagrams as images so I can include it in the .chm I am building w/ Sandcastle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it after a full day of searching. In case anyone ever comes across this again:

Two ways to do this:

1. **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Diagrams.Diagram.CreateBitmap()** lets you pass in a collection of shapes and export them as a bitmap
2. **Microsoft.VisualStudio.EnterpriseTools.Shell.DiagramExporter** is slightly more complicated, but lets you create your own implementation of IServiceProvider, then you can choose locations, file formats, etc.

Slightly more information is available in [this MS forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/vsx/thread/28657edc-abb7-45cb-9334-05c4acf30c2f).

Comment: Please query with Microsoft if you can use the classes from Microsoft namespace. You might hit the rock and violate VS-EULA.