# adding class diagrams from VS2008 to Sandcastle help file

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, sandcastle, class-diagram, helpfile

I've made class diagrams for my projects in Visual Studio 2008 Team System and I want to embed these diagrams in my Sandcastle .chm file.  I keep finding references to the [Drawbridge component](http://www.castleapps.com/) for Sandcastle but they apparently dealt with an older version of Sandcastle; not surprising since it looks like Drawbridge was last updated in 2008.  With the current version of Sandcastle I have in Vista, it is installed at C:\Program Files\Sandcastle Help File Builder.  Upon installing Drawbridge, it created the following directory structure:  C:\Program Files\EWSoftware\Sandcastle Help File Builder\BuildComponents.  It then put an XML component configuration file there, but of course this means nothing to the version of Sandcastle I have installed because that's not anywhere in its path.

I was hoping to just copy over the XML configuration file to Sandcastle's current install directory, but there is no BuildComponents directory there.  So, does anyone know if Drawbridge still works with Sandcastle?  If it does, how can I install it?  If not, how can I embed VS2008 class diagrams in my Sandcastle .chm help file?

This is slightly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540476/can-i-programmatically-export-class-diagrams-from-visual-studio-2008).

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question http://shfb.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=29055 on the SHFB forums says that Drawbridge seems unmaintained, but that you might be able to get it to work with the latest SHFB via assembly redirection.  Another suggestion there is to use the [modeling powertoys](http://modeling.codeplex.com/) and export class diagrams that way.

Hope that helps -- would be interested to hear if you get it working :-)